# Remove a ScreenSpaceLines3D Object from a ViewPort?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, dll, 3d, nullreferenceexception

I am making a 3D Game with WPF in VB, and I am using a ScrennSpaceLines3D Object I found 
http://3dtools.codeplex.com/releases/view/2058
but when I try to remove a line I added to the viewport by using

```
    mainViewport.Children.RemoveAt(i)
```

it gives a NullExceptionError. I have read that this is because it does not totally come off the rendering queue. There have been fixes for c#, but I have yet to find one that works with VB. Is there a way to make this work or possibly draw a line in 3D space some other way? I find it quite ridiculous that VB doesn't even have a way to easily draw 3D lines...

Comment: I find it ridiculous that .Net doesn't come with a decent charting tool as well ... but not much we can do. Did you consider picking up C#? :). Also, you have a typo in `ScrennSpaceLines3D`, should be `Screen` I believe ... [Seems like that library you use wasn't updated since 2007 ... just saying ...]

Comment: Well,2 reasons why I'm not picking up C#: 1.My computer class uses VB. 2. I would rather use C++ than C#, but I can't use either so that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ScreenSpaceLines3D :

```
            foreach (ScreenSpaceLines3D line3D in lines3DList)
            {
                lines3D.Points.Clear(); // Very importante
                _viewport3D.Children.Remove(lines3D);
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party but i'm having the same issues.

The access violation occurs because each instance registers an event handler to the Rendering event of the composition target

```
public ScreenSpaceLines3D()
{
    ...

    CompositionTarget.Rendering += OnRender; // <-- this line
}
```

but forgets to remove it when the instance is removed from the scene.

So to fix this you need to touch the source code:

```
public ScreenSpaceLines3D()
{
    ...

    // event registration removed
}

private bool AttachedToCompositionTargetRendering { get; set; }

protected override void OnVisualParentChanged(DependencyObject oldParent)
{
    base.OnVisualParentChanged(oldParent);

    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);

    if (parent == null)
    {
        if (AttachedToCompositionTargetRendering)
        {
            CompositionTarget.Rendering -= OnRender;

            AttachedToCompositionTargetRendering = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!AttachedToCompositionTargetRendering)
        {
            CompositionTarget.Rendering += OnRender;

            AttachedToCompositionTargetRendering = true;
        }
    }
}
```